# postMessage to iframe then re-broadcast to all parents?

Tags: javascript, iframe

Here is the use case:

I have 3 fronts ends on 3 different subdomains, a.domain.com b.domain.com and c.domain.com
Each front end loads an iframe located at iframe.domain.com

```
 <iframe src="https://iframe.domain.com" sandbox="allow-scripts"></iframe>
```

What I'm trying to achieve, is having one of the app, let's say a.domain.com, that posts a message to the loaded iframe, then have the iframe broadcast the message so that all front ends can receive the message.

I have this JS code in each front end

```
 window.addEventListener('message', (__e) => {        
    console.log('RECEIVED',  __e.data );           
});
```

And I have this JS code in the iframe

```
 window.addEventListener('message', (__e) => {        
    console.log( "INSIDE IFRAME received: " + __e.data );

    //here , I guess I have to rebroacast to all parents ? How ?        
    //parent.postMessage(__e.data ,"*"); does not seems to work 

});
```

When I do, from a.domain.com front end

```
 window.postMessage('test', '*');
```

only a.domain.com receives the message. So I'm trying to rebroadcast to all parents who have the iframe embedded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`postMessage` lets you communicate, across origins, between frames and windows.

It doesn't transmit messages between *copies* of documents.

i.e. If Window A sends a message to Frame A containing document X, then that message is received by the **instance** of that document in that frame.

If you also have Window B including Frame B which *also* contains document X, then that's a **different instance** of the document and will know nothing about the message from Window A and can't rebroadcast it to Window A.

---

You're looking at the wrong technology. You want to look at [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) (or possibly [Socket.io](https://socket.io/) which is a wrapper around them and some other technologies).

With a WebSocket, Window A can send a message to Server X which can rebroadcast it to other WebSocket clients.

Comment: Thanks, yes I already did the implementation via socket, I was just wondering if there was a way to use postMessage this way

Comment: @Eric — No. The first part of this answer explains why.